# Correct way of formatting logging

Tags: java, logging, slf4j

Here are a few ways to do logging. 
Using SLF4J:

What's a best/right way to do it?

```
log.debug(John + " has " + number +" apples with him");
log.debug("{} has {} apples with him", John, number);
log.debug(format("%s has %d apples with him", John, number));
```

Comment: `format` will happen no matter what. IIRC  the logger format will only happen if it is enabled. Go with second option.

Comment: Ah I see thanks. Is `{}` handled by slf4j and not the external logger?

Comment: No, it should be handled by the actual implementation, but I believe it's part of the specification so it needs to do it after checking. Again, if I remember correctly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The second option,

```
log.debug("{} has {} apples with him", John, number);
```

is the "right" way to do it.

Parameterized logging was introduced to avoid the expense of computing a formatted string when the message isn't even enabled. This requires that you pass the format specification and the necessary arguments to the logger. The logger only completes the formatting operation if it is enabled.

The other two options preemptively format the message, even if it won't be logged.

Comment: Do all Loggers support the `{}` call?

Comment: @StenKin sfl4j loggers should.